# Processing SSAS 2012 cube using SSIS 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, ssas, visual-studio-2005, cube

I have a cube which is build in SASS Version 2012 and i need to process it through Analysis Services Processing Task  SSIS version 2005 , Is it Possible ? Any inputs will be Appreciated ?
Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

1. You can try Processing Task from SSIS 2005. Basically, it queries SSAS Cube structure and presents it to you in a designer. Based on your input, it creates an XMLA script and executes it.
2. You can create an XMLA Processing script in SSMS, and use it in **Analysis Services Execute DDL Task**.

Beware that you need a proper version of BIDS (Visual Studio) do create a valid package for SSIS 2005.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script task that issues the xmla commands to process the cube.